# How to hide the legend in a tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to hide the legends in the following `tikzpicture` code. However, after I use `every axis legend/.code={\let\addlegendentry\relax}`, it messes up the picture. Could someone help me how I can fix this?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
   width=10cm,
   height=5cm,
   scale only axis,
   xmin=0.8, xmax=3.2,
   xtick={1,2,3},
   xmajorgrids,
   ymin=0, ymax=1,
   ylabel={$\phi$},
   ymajorgrids,
   axis lines*=left,
   legend style ={ at={(1.03,1)}, 
        anchor=north west, draw=black, 
        fill=white,align=left},
    cycle list name=black white,
    smooth,
    every axis legend/.code={\let\addlegendentry\relax},
]

   \addplot coordinates{
      (1,0.35)
      (2,0.41)
      (3,0.49) 
   };
   \addlegendentry{$S1$=2.5};

   \addplot coordinates{
      (1,0.32)
      (2,0.46)
      (3,0.61) 
   };
   \addlegendentry{$S2$=3.5};

   \addplot coordinates{
      (1,0.31)
      (2,0.46)
      (3,0.51) 
   };
   \addlegendentry{$S3$=4.0};

   \addplot coordinates{
      (1,0.20)
      (2,0.33)
      (3,0.58) 
    };
    \addlegendentry{$S4$=4.5};

   \addplot coordinates{
      (1,0.25)
      (2,0.42)
      (3,0.48) 
    };
    \addlegendentry{$S5$=5.0};

    \addplot coordinates{
      (1,0.32)
      (2,0.40)
      (3,0.58) 
    };
    \addlegendentry{$S6$=6.0};

   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Here is the output of the above code.

[image]

Comment: One option: instead of your attempt with `\relax`, use `\legend{}` as the last item inside the `axis` environment. This will clear any generated legend entries and cause the legend to be excluded from output.

Comment: @A2009: Do you have a particular reason for not simply removing the `\addlegendentry` commands? That way, the legend will also be deactivated.

Comment: @Jake: I wanted to temporarily deactivate them with the most simplest way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using `\relax`, which drops the arguments to `\addlegendentry{...}` and causes them to be erroneously set as text at the axis origin, use `\legend{}` (empty) at the end of the `axis` environment. This empties the legend and, as a result, it is not typeset in the output.

I've simplified your MWE quite a bit here; in the future, please only show code relevant to your question.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \addplot {x};
  \addlegendentry{foo};
  \addplot {x^2};
  \addlegendentry{bar};
  \legend{}; % empty the legend so as not to print it
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]